# Laravel how to translate the name of an input field

Tags: php, laravel

In my `laravel`-application I have some input fields like this:

```
<input name="phone" type="tel" pattern="^[0-9-+s()]*$" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefonnr." required>

<input name="subject" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Thema" required>
```

...and so on

and in my Controller I have this:

```
$validator = Validator::make(request()->all(), [
   'email' => ['required', 'email'],
   'name' => ['required', 'string'],
   'phone' => ['string'],
   'subject' => ['required', 'string'],
   'message' => ['required', 'string'],
   'conditions' => ['accepted', 'boolean'],
]);
```

So far so good, but now I want to customize the error messages. Right now, the error messages are like:

```
"subject muss ausgefüllt sein"
```

or

```
"phone muss angegeben sein"
```

So, how can I change it to:

```
"Thema muss ausgefüllt sein"
```

or

```
"Telefonnummer muss angegeben sein"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.3 return custom error message using $this->validate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40067212/laravel-5-3-return-custom-error-message-using-this-validate)

Answer (score 3):

You can set custom message in third param of `make` ..

```
$validator = Validator::make(
   request()->all(), // data
   [  //rules
   'email' => ['required', 'email'],
   'name' => ['required', 'string'],
   'phone' => ['string'],
   'subject' => ['required', 'string'],
   'message' => ['required', 'string'],
   'conditions' => ['accepted', 'boolean'],
  ],
  [ //messages
  'subject.required' => 'Thema muss ausgefüllt sein'
]);
```

Source Code https://github.com/illuminate/validation/blob/3ec97a34466541c5802c5da44c831499e32c28ef/Factory.php#L98

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks! :-)

Comment: What is the case when multiple languages must be included?

Comment: `$enMessages = []; $duMessages = []` ... Based on the lang, use that arr maybe? @ST80

Comment: @ST80 It is so easy look [official doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/localization)

Answer (score 1):

```
        $messages = [
                'subject.required' => 'Telefonnummer muss angegeben sein',
 'subject.string' => 'YOUR CUSTOM MESSAGE',

            ];


        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => ['required', 'email'],
   'name' => ['required', 'string'],
   'phone' => ['string'],
   'subject' => ['required', 'string'],
   'message' => ['required', 'string'],
   'conditions' => ['accepted', 'boolean'],
        ], $messages);
```