# How to change the default validation error message in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to change the default validation error message. I don't know how to do that, currently I am seeing this default message:

> The quote name field is required

But I want to show message like this:

> The quote name is required.

How can I achieve this?

**Controller**

```
                    public function store(Request $request)
                    {
                     $this->validate($request,[
                    'quote_name'=>'required',
                    'height' =>'required',
                    'width' => 'required',
                    'quote_placement'=>'required',
                    'order_fabric'=>'required',
                    'instruction'=>'required',
                    'image' =>'required'
                     ]);
                     }
```

Comment: DON'T YELL. THAT'S NOT WELCOME

Comment: You can refer this answer, hope it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40068312/6000629

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read this [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#customizing-the-error-messages)

```
public function messages()
{
  return [
     'quote_name.required'=> 'your custom error message',
     'height.required' =>'your custom error message',
     'width.required' => 'your custom error message',
     'quote_placement.required'=>'your custom error message',
     'order_fabric.required'=>'your custom error message',
     'instruction.required'=>'your custom error message',
     'image.required' =>'your custom error message'
  ];
}
```